# Обособление оборота с союзом КАК

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли вторая запятая для обособления оборота с союзом КАК?

*А вот сонно шевелится громадная, как гора, птица Рух. Перья её торчат несколько вкось. Шея голая, облезлая. Рядом с мощной, **как дубовый ствол**(,) ногой, валяется небрежно расклёванный остов буйвола.* *Птица стара. Всё на свете ей надоело. И пары для Руха нет. Последний остался.*

У автора запятой нет, но как это можно объяснить?

Comment: Может, всё-таки это промах корректоров? Ведь не один раз участники указывали на ошибки в книгах этого автора. Или вы думаете, что в этом случае можно применить правило: *"Определения, носящие характер пояснения... отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится..."*?

Comment: Да я не знаю :)) Но это правило вроде бы не подходит.  Пояснительные определения другие;  там обычно на первом месте стоит местоименное или очень общее по значению слово,  требующее пояснения.

Comment: Ну да, не очень подходит. Там всё про баню: *...остатки прежней, сгоревшей бани*. И *очередной, шестой том*.

Comment: Тогда придумайте что-нибудь еще... хорошо бы в ответе.

Comment: Нетушки! В этот раз оправдывать отсутствие запятой не буду. Интонация без паузы здесь нам тоже не в помощь.

Comment: Емец никогда не ошибается, у него правильное чувство языка.  Мне нужны оправдательные версии и похожие примеры. Хотя бы по структуре.  В принципе оборот можно рассматривать как несогласованное определение.

Comment: Действительно, может, всё же подходит это правило? *"Мощные"* бывают разные, вот и поясняется одно определение другим, пусть и с "как".

Comment: Александр, а почему вы никак не хотите отказаться от пояснительных определений и считать их просто однородными. Ведь это разные вещи. Пояснительные определения оформляются и читаются как однородные, но мы по семантике определяем их неоднородность. Настоящие однородные определения независимы, равноправны и раскрывают общую тему. Если мы обособляем сравнительный оборот, то отношения между определениями зависимые и по графике, и по произношению. А если я хочу их сделать равноправными, можно это сделать? Просто приравняем оборот к несогласованному однородному определению.

Comment: Простите, но "правильное чувство языка" не пропустило бы "как дубовый ствол ногой", независимо от того, можно ли применить сюда формальное правило, разрешающее не использовать запятую.

Comment: Ну пусть будет так, но очень уж нестандартное это определение - оно ведь как бы больше относится к "мощной", без которой получится "Рядом с как дубовый ствол ногой" (если мы их считаем равноправными и однородными).

Comment: О, сколько критики!  В оправдание себя и любимого писателя я приведу примеры несогласованных определений:  «Она сняла со стола толстую, с бахромой скатерть и постелила другую, белую».  «Между тем в приземистой, с коричневыми стенами  зимовке Клюшиных действительно горела пока слегка увернутая семилинейная лампа». И попробую объяснить однородность. Нога мощная, нога как дубовый ствол. Каждое из однородных определений относится непосредственно к определяемому слову. При обособлении оборота он становится зависимым и поясняет слово «мощный», которое является основным определением.

Comment: Почему бы нам не выйти за эти рамки привычного.  Давайте переставим слова,  все же любят всякого рода переделки (здесь вырежем, там приклеим), то есть довольно свободно обращаются с текстом. Тогда получается: Рядом с ногой, мощной, как дубовый ствол, валяется... В постпозиции определения автоматически становятся однородными, и разве они не похожи на однородные? Просто мы привыкли к стандартной графике, все запредельное кажется нам чуждым.

Comment: Вот и хорошо! В комментариях мы, точнее, вы нашли ответ, как часто бывает, чуть-чуть за рамками правил, что снова апеллирует к их несовершенству, а лучше сказать, к их расширительной трактовке и свободе, позволяющей маневрировать в поле тончайших нюансов.

Comment: Емец ошибается. Я читал кое-что из его книг до издательской корректуры. Там хватает косяков.

Comment: Я не знаю, Александр, просто это мое мнение.  Может, это и правда ошибка корректоров. У автора много нестандартных конструкций, которые  воспринимаются именно так.  Косяки!  Неужели так плохо работают корректоры в очень хорошо изданной книге.  Все необычное раздражает публику, то есть, я хотела сказать, вдумчивых и требовательных читателей.

Comment: Напишите ему сами и спросите) Он в ВК есть и открыт к общению.